# JSON.parse(...).logout is not a function in keycloak

Tags: json, reactjs, keycloak, stringify, jsonparser

When I going to use keycloak.logout(), it shows a error **JSON.parse(...).logout is not a function**
I added and got keycloak object using sessionStorage.but when I logged it in the console , the logout function was not in the keyloack object.So that the the above error occured.

**This is my code to set the keycloak object.**

```
const keycloak = Keycloak('/keycloak.json');
      keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required'}).then(authenticated => {
        this.setState({ keycloak: keycloak, authenticated: authenticated })

        sessionStorage.setItem('keycloak', JSON.stringify(keycloak))
```

**This is my code to get the keycloak object. and call logout()**

```
JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('keycloak')).logout()
```

Comment: Functions cannot be serialised/deserialised to/from JSON using `JSON.stringify/parse`. So `logout` cannot be a function ...and yet you are trying to invoke it as a function.

Comment: @BenAston Isn't there a solution to this

Comment: Do you really want to serialize functionality? It's a security risk.

Comment: @BenAston yes, it's fine. If there is a way to use the logout() function

Comment: To serialise the a function you can use `Function#toString` (ie. the method located on the `Function` prototype). You can then run the string as a function by using `eval`. You almost never want to do this, however. But you might have found an exceptional case.